# Проблема с instagram api

Tags: javascript, api, instagram

Добрый день. Столкнулся с такой проблемой: получаю от апишки инстаграма все необходимые данные (clien_id, токен) и по запросу вывожу все свои фотографии, с этим проблем не возникает. Но когда пытаюсь вывести фотографии по тегу или фотографии другого пользователя(зная айдишник) апи просто ничего не возвращает, не выдает никаких ошибок. Если кто-нибудь сможет объяснить причину, буду благодарен. Есть вариант, что либо я что-то делаю не так, либо инстаграм разрешает сейчас выводить только при наличии токена для определенного пользователя

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все вы так делаете. Это внутренняя политика Instagram (точнее головной компании Facebook), направленная на ограничение использования своего API. Официально для получения разрешений на работу с тегами и контентом другим пользователей вам потребуется пройти процедуру review вашего приложения и получить permission `public_content`.

На практике такое разрешение получить нереально, так что переходите на их Private API (который несильно отличается от официального). На GitHub есть много различных решений как использовать их неофициальное API, изучайте код, пишите свое решение. Единственный момент, это надо делать через сервер, там есть привязка к IP-адресу, поэтому через JavaScript на клиентской стороне при всем желании будет сложно от них что-нибудь получить.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Curly_Dog в общем, вбивайте на гитхабе Instagram Private API и адаптируйте готовые решения под свои цели. единственное замечание, когда будете делать первый запрос на авторизацию (с данными пользователя) - открывайте приложение на телефоне, где уже залогинен этот пользователь, делаете запрос с сервера, приложение начинает ругаться - ставите галочку типа "да, все норм, это я"))) тогда авторизация пройдет хорошо, можно будет делать запросы.